# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package PYTHON

Tags: python, import, python-3.8, workdir

I am trying to import some functions and variables from the parent directory.

Here is what my dir looks like:

[image]

I want the import:

-- send_invoice func from bifatura_methods.py

-- start func from xml_generator.py

-- data_json_1, data_json_2 dicts from inputs.py

TO send_ticari_satis_invoice.py.

My working dir is:

```
/home/selman/PycharmProjects/15.0/custom_addons/Invoice_Integration/models/tests
```

When I tried for imports like:

```
from ..bifatura_methods import send_invoice
from ..xml_generator import start
from inputs import data_json_1, data_json_2
```

Output:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

When I tried this:

```
from custom_addons.Invoice_Integration.models.bifatura_methods import send_invoice
from custom_addons.Invoice_Integration.models.xml_generator import start
from custom_addons.Invoice_Integration.models.tests.inputs import data_json_1,data_json_2
```

Output:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'models' from 'odoo' (unknown location)
```

Any advice and help are welcome! Thank you community :)

Comment: have you tried adding an init.py to your tests dir?

Answer (score 2):

since your `\tests` is essentially a module you're importing into, you should add an empty `__init__.py` inside `\tests`.

I personally would use explicit imports:

```
from models.bifatura_methods import send_invoice
from models.xml_generator import start
```

IMO, this would help you keep your sanity if you end up having a lot more submodules.

Comment: i created a empty __init__.py into my /tests dir. When i use your code its give me error. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

Comment: do relative imports work now?

Comment: from your code it seems like there are many layers to your application, maybe try editing the post to include the whole structure if possible?

Comment: if you are using the debug or run function on your editor, you might want to take note of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py

it matters where you run the .py script from, and your debug/launch configuration should allow you to specify the exact way you need it to be run.

Comment: @Selman sorry forgot to mention you

Comment: i updated my question. You can see the full structure. I don't know what is relative imports but i will learn quickly and i will give you feedback. Thank you for being so helpful ! @marcus jwt

Answer (score 2):

You can check the Odoo [guidelines](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/contributing/development/coding_guidelines.html?highlight=relative%20imports#imports) that we use `from odoo.addons` to import from Odoo addons (custom addons should also work)

***Example:***

```
from odoo.addons.Invoice_Integration.bifatura_methods import send_invoice
```